# Laravel cargar miles de registros en una variable sin que demore mucho

Tags: laravel-8

Tengo una tabla con miles de registro y cuando intento cargar todos los registros demora demasiado.

```
$users = Users::all();
```

En SQL hago la consulta y se demora aproximadamente 18 seg:

```
SELET * FROM Users
```

Pero usando Laravel se demora casi 2 min en cargar esa consulta. Existe alguna manera de reducir ese tiempo de carga en Laravel

Comment: 18 segundos ya me parece una barbaridad.  ¿para que quieres guardar todos esos datos en una variable?  Vas a petar al servidor si es algo frecuente en tu modo de programación.

Comment: Lo hacia para poder trabajar con esa variable para luego sacar por ejemplo la cantidad de registros que haciendo esto $users = Users::all()->count(); se demora muchísimo también, o cuando quiero saber cuantos Users hay de cierto país igual se demora muchísimo.

Comment: A ver, ese tipo de consultas debes hacerlas contra el servidor de base de datos, que **teóricamente** estan preparados para eso (sino no los usariamos), y no a traves de una variable con un contenido tan grande.  Que no te de miedo inundar de consultas a la base de datos, pero haz que estas sean razonables e intenta conseguir los datos minimos necesarios que necesitas en cada consulta, para que las consultas sean ágiles, y no toda una tabla para jugar con ella despues en PHP.  El porque tarda tanto en realizar una consulta es otro tema y quizas tiene que ver con una mala indexación de columnas

Comment: y como pudiera hacer una consulta contra el servidor de base de datos, no entendí esa parte, porque que yo sepa al usar Users::all()->count(); la consulta la hace al servidor de base de datos.

Comment: ¿si haces un `Users::count()` te funciona y tarda lo mismo?  ¿o va más rápido?

Comment: uff que rápido, ahora entiendo lo que me querías explicar. gracias

Comment: Cuando haces un `Users::all()->count()` lo que estás haciendo es volcar toda la tabla, por lo tanto es como si haces el `SELECT * FROM Users` y **después** le haces el count()  a eso que acabas de volcar, por eso tarda tanto. Lo cual no es necesario teniendo el `Users::count();` que tan solo cuenta los registros sin volcarlos.

Comment: pero cuando quiero hacer esto por ejemplo Users::where('active',1)->count(); tardaría mucho o hay una sintaxis para optimizar esto

Comment: Si esa consulta te tarda mucho entonces deberias plantearte, en la base de datos, agregar un **indice** en la columna `active` para mejorar la rapidez de esa consulta.

Comment: las tablas no las puedo modificar ya que solo tengo permisos de lectura y mandarlas a modificar crearía un problema para el core de otras aplicaciones, déjame ver como manejo ese tema. gracias por la ayuda